# D3 filling dataset from csv failing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm very new to D3 but am trying to convert some bl.ock code to my requirements.

The example I'm using has a static dictionary of data within the html file - I'm trying to switch this to use data from a csv.

My csv is as follows:

category,measure
Sam,0.3
Peter,0.25
John,0.15
Rick,0.05
Lenny,0.18
Paul,0.04
Steve,0.03

The code I've tried is as follows:

```
var dataset = d3.map();
dataset = d3.csv("http://blahblah/testingtesting/DThree/PieChart.csv"
                , function(d) { dataset.set(d.category, +d.measure); }) 

function dsPieChart() {

    var width = 400,
        height = 400,
        outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
        innerRadius = outerRadius * .999,
        // for animation
        innerRadiusFinal = outerRadius * .5,
        innerRadiusFinal3 = outerRadius * .45,
        color = d3.scale.category20() 
    ;

    var vis = d3.select("#pieChart")
        .append("svg:svg")
        .data([dataset])
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("svg:g") 
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")")
    ;
    ..
    ...
    ....
```

The pie does not appear when using the above - is there a scope problem, in that filling dataset outside of `dsPieChart()` means it is not reachable, or am I just not using d3.csv correctly ?

---

note

The original code looked like this:

```
function dsPieChart() {

    var dataset = [{
        category: "Sam",
        measure: 0.30
    }, {
        category: "Peter",
        measure: 0.25
    }, {
        category: "John",
        measure: 0.15
    }, {
        category: "Rick",
        measure: 0.05
    }, {
        category: "Lenny",
        measure: 0.18
    }, {
        category: "Paul",
        measure: 0.04
    }, {
        category: "Steve",
        measure: 0.03
    }];



    var width = 400,
        height = 400,
        outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
        innerRadius = outerRadius * .999,
        // for animation
        innerRadiusFinal = outerRadius * .5,
        innerRadiusFinal3 = outerRadius * .45,
        color = d3.scale.category20() //builtin range of colors
    ;


    var vis = d3.select("#pieChart")
        .append("svg:svg") //create the SVG element inside the <body>
        .data([dataset]) //associate our data with the document
        .attr("width", width) //set the width and height of our visualization (these will be attributes of the <svg> tag
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("svg:g") //make a group to hold our pie chart
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")") //move the center of the pie chart from 0, 0 to radius, radius
    ;
```

Comment: Is your CSV actually in one line?

Comment: @JNF thanks - formatting problem - I'll amend now

Comment: Why do you do `dataset = d3.csv(...`? I don't think `csv` returns a dataset.

Comment: @JNF so how do I change things to read correctly from the csv into this bit ` .data([dataset]) `

Comment: Remove `dataset =` from that line

Comment: @JNF ok - I got rid of `dataset =` and no piechart. So then I tried moving it all inside `function dsPieChart() {` but still no piechart.

Comment: Can you http://jsfiddle.net this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
d3.csv("file.csv", function(rows)
    {
        //rows is an array of json objects containing the data in from the csv
        dataset = rows.map(function(d)
        {
            //each d is one line of the csv file represented as a json object                
            return {"category": d.category, "measure": +d.measure} ;
        })
       dsPieChart();
    })
```

Took cue from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/1525346)